# messages are not delivered with twilio?

Tags: python, twilio

I have been using Twilio RestApi for sending messages.The message log says Messages are sent but they are not delivered.2 to 3 messages were delivered at first but now its creating the problem.My app also throws no error.Please help.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
account_sid = "........sid......."
auth_token = ".....token......"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages.create(to="+919821320844", from_="+13617923488", body="msg.....!")
print "sent
```

Comment: Could you please post your code of what you have attempted so far?

Comment: You should paste your code into your question (by editing) and not the comments :).

Comment: Hi, Twilio evangelist here. Is the from number your Twilio number? Are you on a trial or full account? If on trial, have you added the to number as a trusted number on your account?

Comment: yes I have added the to number on my account and I am on trial account and from number is my twilio number

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Because I noticed your `to` number is from India, I think it is worth having a look into [this](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices). Especially item 3 that says:

> If you’ve been seeing delivery delays when sending to Indian numbers,
>   make sure you are making the requests during the operational hours of
>   9 A.M. to 9 P.M., as overnight messages are likely to be cached until
>   the next day.

This is a limitation in India, so likely what is happening to you right now, and why it worked before. Maybe try sending to another number outside of India?

Comment: So is there any solution for this.I needed this service for the whole 24 hours.?

Comment: Will this problem be solved if I upgrade my account?

Comment: They won't. this is a limitation with carriers in India. Likelihood is India will go over this issue, but it's not something we have control of

Answer (score 0):

India's rules are frustrating (maybe well intentioned, but flawed none-the-less), and the problem is not Twilio's. I also use Clickatell for a project and they have the same issues - so unless you can lobby your government for changes, there is not much any vendor can do.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices